# How to select multiple, non-adjacent, columns in Excel filtered table using column names

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy multiple, non-adjacent, columns from filtered table to another sheet. I'm stuck with the multiple selection part:
* The data is from external source -> I can't control original stracture
* The filtering creterias are from columns which I don't need to copy -> I can't skip importing columns that I don't need to copy.
* The table is filtered -> I can't simply select column (e.g. C:C), I need the filtered rows only.

Is it possible doing so by using header names?

I've tried few lines of code (see below) but none of those produced the desired results. If I record a macro I simply get range selections:
***Range("C155:C30230,E155:E30230").Select***

This is what i tried so far, grouped by results:
Note that these is test code so it is not necessarily refer to the same columns
-> Working, but not exactly what I want:
`' this is only one column
Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Email]]").Select`

`' this is full (unfiltered) column selection
Union(ws.Range("C:C"), ws.Range("E:E")).Select`

`'  this is not using header name
Union(ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns(3).Range, ActiveSheet.ListObjects("myTable").ListColumns(5).Range).Select`

->These snippets generatad run-time error "Method 'Range' of object
'_Worksheet' failed":
`Union(Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Email]]").Select, Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Language]]").Select)`

`Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Union(Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Email]]"), Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Language]]"))`

`Union(Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Email]]"), Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Language]]")).Select`

`Union(Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Email]]"), Range("A:A")).Select`

->This snippet generatad error "Compile error: Type mismatch":
`Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Union(Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Email]]").Address, Range("myTable[[#Headers],[Language]]").Address)`

My aim at this stage is to see all the required filtrered table columns selected.
Thank you for looking at this

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

```
Sub x()

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    Union(.ListColumns(1).Range, .ListColumns(3).Range).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Range("A18")
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

There is a good guide to tables [here](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables).

Comment: This works for me but Is it possible to do the same with header names rather than column numbers?

Comment: Yes just use the names instead of the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Using structured references as you show, I think you want something like:

```
Set R = Union(Range("Table1[[#All],[Email]]"), Range("Table1[[#All],[Language]]")).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

R.Copy 'your_destination
```

Some of your errors are related to:

- you are not providing range objects for the arguments to the `Union` method
- you are only providing the Header row to the argument
- Use of `Select` just confuses things and is rarely, if ever, necessary.

Comment: Done that but still getting **"Method 'Range' of object
'_Worksheet' failed"** run-time error. If I use column numbers (e.g. `.ListColumns(1).Range` then it works. If you can solve this then this would be my preferred answer. Thank you

Comment: @HarCo It works here with a table set up with that name and those headers. Without more information as to the real data and exactly what you are doing, I could only guess as to your problem with implementing this solution.  My guess is that the header names (or table name) are not what you think they are.  Maybe some non-printing characters, spaces, etc.  If that is not the case, I'd need to examine the workbook.